# Handle float input crossbrowser

Tags: html, input, user-input, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

in an angular app i need to bind a scope variable to a float user input.

```
<my-float ng-model="myValue" name="floatValue"></my-float>
<button type="button" ng-disable="myValue.$invalid">Submit</submit>
```

The User should be able to insert a decimal number, separated with comma or point and with max two decimal digits.
The html input should show only allowed characters ignoring everything after second decimal digit.

Tests

1. 0 --> ok  --> myValue = 0
2. 0.1 or 0,1--> ok --> myValue = 0.1
3. 0.12 or 0,12 --> ok --> model = 0.12
4. 12 --> ok --> myValue = 12
5. 12.3 or 12,3 --> ok myValue = 12.3
6. 12.34 or 12,34 --> ok myValue= 12.34

   This code resolve my issue :

   ```
   app.directive("myFloat",['$filter',function($filter){
       var FLOAT_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/;
       return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
               ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewValue){
               if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue))
               {
                   ctrl.$setValidity('float', true);
                   var vv = getNewViewValue(viewValue);
                   var floatValue = parseFloat(vv);
                   ctrl.$setViewValue(vv);
                   ctrl.$render();
                   return $filter('truncate')(floatValue);
               }
               else{
                  ctrl.$setValidity('float', false);
               }
               return viewValue;
           });

           var getNewViewValue = function(vv){
               var str = (vv +'').replace(",",".");
               var splitted = str.split(".");

               if(splitted[1] && splitted[1].length > 2){
                  splitted[1] = splitted[1].substring(0,2);
                  return splitted[0]+'.'+ splitted[1];
               }
               return vv;
           };

           ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
               if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue))
               {
                   ctrl.$setValidity('float', true);
                   var vv = getNewViewValue(viewValue);
                   var floatValue = parseFloat(vv);
                   ctrl.$setViewValue(vv);
                   ctrl.$render();
                   return $filter('truncate')(floatValue);
               }
               else {
                   console.log("input not valid");
                   ctrl.$setValidity('float', false);
                   return undefined;
               }
           });
       }
    }
   }]);
   ```

with html

```
 <input name="x" type="text" my-float ng-model="value">
 <div>error:{{f.x.$invalid}}</div>
```

here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FSEncUtlDds6R8VPOCgl?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

I would say , You put myValue as string and for validity you can say :

```
1. if ( myValue[n-2] == ',' or myValue[n-3] ==',')
split the string into two by ,
else split the string into two by .
2. check second splited part is a number and length is less than two else invalid input 
3. check first part is number , If yes a valid input or else invalid
```

Comment: i need to restrict user to see only allowed character ... so i'm trying to use $formatters and $render